# how to find button in cell subview

Tags: ios, uitableview, uibutton

Good day!
Here is a problem: i've added a button in cell in my UITableView programmatically like this:

```
 UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:buttonFrame];

[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Button_off_weather"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

button.tag = indexPath.row;

[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonCityTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[cell addSubview: button];
```

it works fine. 
then i want to find it in table and switch off like this:

```
    NSMutableArray *cells = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (NSInteger j = 0; j < [_tableView numberOfSections]; ++j)
{
    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < [_tableView numberOfRowsInSection:j]; ++i)
    {
        [cells addObject:[_tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:j]]];

        for (UITableViewCell *cell in cells)
        {
            for (id theView in cell.subviews) {

                if ([theView isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
                    [theView performSelector:@selector(buttonOff:)];
                }

            }

        }
    }
}
```

this does not work. is there any ideas?

Comment: Please share your question clearly.

Answer (score 3):

Create a custom cell subclass with an `@property` making the button available. This is the correct approach to take.

Your current approach is currently and will in the future be error prone. Try not to rely on code which traverses view hierarchies, particularly if you don't have control over some parts of the view hierarchy (like the cell subviews).

Comment: thank you for your advice! i'll do it like you said.

Answer (score 1):

use enumeration with `[cell.contentView subviews]`

```
 for(UIView *view in [cell.contentView subviews])
    {
        if([view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
        {
                        [theView performSelector:@selector(buttonOff:)];

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check This: Works fine for me.

```
int sections = [self.tableView numberOfSections];
    for (int i=0; i<sections; i++) {
        //For the Custom cell 
        NSIndexPath *myIP = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:i] ;
        CellStar *cell =(CellStar *) [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:myIP];

        UITextView *txtVi ;

        NSArray *subviews = cell.contentView.subviews;

        for(id element in subviews) {
            if ([element isKindOfClass:[UITextView class]]){
                 NSLog(@"element is a UItextView\n");
                txtVi =  (UITextView *)element;

            }
            if([element isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]){
                UIButton *btn = (UIButton *) element;

                 NSLog(@"element is UIButton\n");
            }
        }
        //[self.tableView reloadData];
    }
```